# Fetch proxy url from pacfile on iOS native

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, browserstack

We have an app with both native iOS and Android parts, and Flutter pages. We're currently transitioning from pure native to Flutter. Recently our organisation has been looking into using browserstack for testing our app. However, Flutter pages on their iOS devices dont work, we can't instantiate the proxy correctly. We've managed to get this to work for Android by using the [device_proxy](https://pub.dev/packages/device_proxy) package, which returns the correct configuration for Android, but not for iOS. For iOS it only looks at hostname and port values in the first proxy object, but Browserstack uses an autoconfiguration file.

When adding some print statements and looping through all values on Browserstack I can find values like this:

- key:kCFProxyAutoConfigurationURLKey,
  value:http://$SomeIp:$SomePort/pacfile?device=$SomeDeviceId
- key:kCFProxyTypeKey, value:kCFProxyTypeAutoConfigurationURL
- key:kCFProxyTypeKey, value:kCFProxyTypeNone

If I follow the URL of the pacfile I can download it, mail it to myself and view the contents. It's a very simple pacfile:

```
 function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
      return "PROXY $SomeIp:$SomeOtherPort";
    }
```

So the IP is always the same as the ip of the pacfile, but the port differs per device (I think it's hosting location dependant).

So I have to somehow get the url from the file, but how?

If I start up a session, check the pacfile, hard code this url in a next version of my app, and return it in my findProxyFromEnvironment in my HttpOverride in Dart it does work, but ofcourse this is not dynamic or workable (I honestly hate my life atm for debugging in this way)

What is a good way to achieve this? I'm not that familiar with the iOS ecosystem (I honestly try to stay away from it as much as I can, we don't like eachother)

What I've tried so far has been largely inspired by what I found [here](https://gitlab.com/yamsergey/platform_proxy/-/blob/master/ios/Classes/YSFPPProxiesResolver.m). It's a package which is not yet ready according to the developer, but should probably do what I need. It is in Obj-c though, and my iOS experience only encompasses Swift. I got this so far:

```
class ProxyMethodCallHandler: FlutterMethodCallHandlerProtocol {
    
    static var emit: ((SingleEvent<Any?>) -> Void)? = nil
    func handle() -> Single<Any?> {
        
        guard let proxySettings = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()?.takeUnretainedValue(),
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") else {
                return Single.just("")
        }
        let proxies = CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL((url as CFURL), proxySettings).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray
        guard let settings = proxies.firstObject as? NSDictionary,
            let _ = settings.object(forKey: (kCFProxyTypeKey as String)) as? String else {
                return Single.just("")
        }
        for proxy in proxies {
            if let proxyDictionary = proxy as? NSDictionary {
                if let autoconfigUrl = proxyDictionary.value(forKey: (kCFProxyAutoConfigurationURLKey as String)), let proxyURL = URL(string: String(describing: autoconfigUrl)) as CFURL?, let hostCfUrl = url as CFURL? {
                    
                    return Single.create { (singleEvent: @escaping (SingleEvent<Any?>) -> Void) -> Disposable in
                        ProxyMethodCallHandler.emit = singleEvent
                        var context = CFStreamClientContext(version: CFIndex(0), info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
                        let runLoopSource = CFNetworkExecuteProxyAutoConfigurationURL(proxyURL , hostCfUrl, {(_, proxies, __ ) in
                            if let proxyArray = proxies as? [Dictionary<CFString, Any>] {
                                var message = ""
                                for dictionary in proxyArray {
                                    for (key, value) in dictionary {
                                        message = "\(message);key: \(key) with type \(key.self), value: \(value)"
                                    }
                                    if let host = dictionary[kCFProxyHostNameKey], let port = dictionary[kCFProxyPortNumberKey]{
                                        ProxyMethodCallHandler.emitIfPresent(url: "\(host):\(port)")
                                    }
                                }
                                ProxyMethodCallHandler.emitIfPresent(url: "No proxies in array but dit find \(message)")
                            } else {
                                ProxyMethodCallHandler.emitIfPresent(url: "Not a Dictionary<String,String>")
                            }
                        }, &context)

                        let runLoop: CFRunLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
                        CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop, runLoopSource.takeUnretainedValue(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
                        CFRunLoopRun()
                        CFRunLoopRemoveSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource.takeUnretainedValue(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
                        return Disposables.create()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Single.just("")
    }
    
    static func emitIfPresent(url: String){
        if let emit = emit {
            emit(.success(url))
            ProxyMethodCallHandler.emit = nil
        }
    }
}
```

There is some debugging stuff in there, and the static implementation is pretty gnarly, and I have no clue what types some things are so, but it does seem to return what I want, but the app now never actually paints my Flutter app, it is as if it's stuck on something. I know it does emit a value over my methodchannel as I can see the print statement on the Flutter side where I do receive the correct ip and port.

I have absolutly **NO** idea what the run loop stuff does, I just copied it from the obj-c implementation of the previously mentioned package [here](https://gitlab.com/yamsergey/platform_proxy/-/blob/master/ios/Classes/YSFPPProxiesResolver.m) and adapted it to Swift (I think?)

But, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something stupid, this should not be so hard as I'm making it, any way to do this more cleanly or simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found something that works.

If I change this:

```
let runLoop: CFRunLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop, runLoopSource.takeUnretainedValue(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
CFRunLoopRun()
CFRunLoopRemoveSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource.takeUnretainedValue(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
```

To just this:

```
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runloopSource.takeUnretainedValue(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
```

and don't mess with anything else, it runs.

It's not pretty, but it works, and we're only using it for test builds so it's slighlty less unacceptable.

I'm still open to suggestions on how to get this to work properly...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the plugin available [here](https://github.com/kaivean/system_proxy)? This should help in reading the system's proxy settings.

Comment: Just looked at the code, it returns the proxy array from CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings. This can give me the settings such as the proxy type, and in case for aan autoconfigurationURL it could give me the url, but I would still need to either download the file or call it to return a value. And thats the bit I'm getting stuck at.